# How to load all the PRISM modules in runtime?

Tags: c#, module, unity-container, prism, mef

In the meanwhile, I was creating module catalogs to load the modules using Unity. I've seen several applications which can load all the modules in a certain folder, I mean.. the application can load the modules in runtime.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Do you want to load the modules at runtime without having a reference to them in the Shell project? Yes this is possible.

Comment: yes, that's what I want. I was seeing DirectoryModuleCatalog in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have på override the GetModuleCatalog method in the Bootstrapper and return a new DirectoryModuleCatalog. See this question: [Prism v4 Loading modules on demand with DirectoryModuleCatalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920391/prism-v4-loading-modules-on-demand-with-directorymodulecatalog).